# Left outer join of multiple files data using awk command

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I have base file and multiple files having common data based on 1st field of base file. I need output file with combination of all data. I have tried many commands due to file size taking to much time for output many times awk helps me out but i don't have any idea of awk array programing
example

**Base File**

```
aa
ab
ac
ad
ae
```

**File -1**

```
aa,Apple
ab,Orange
ac,Mango
```

**File -2**

```
aa,1
ab,2
ae,3
```

**Output File expected**

```
aa,Apple,1
ab,Orange,2
ac,Mango,
ad,,
ae,,3
```

This is what I tried:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next}{if(b=a[$1]) print b,$2; else print $1 }' OFS=, test.txt test2.txt
```

Comment: so what did you try so far? Please note there are plenty of similar questions out there

Comment: i have tried 'join' command but ouput too much delayed.

Comment: then show the exact command together with its output. You may be close to the solution.

Comment: this was i have used awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next}{if(b=a[$1]) print b,$2; else print $1 }' OFS=, test.txt test2.txt .. but output is incomplete.

Comment: What if you have a key value in file1 or file2 that didn't exist in your base file, eg. `af`?

Answer (score 1):

You could try 2 successive `join`. Something like the following function should work :

```
join -a 1 -t, -e '' -o auto <(join -a 1 -t, -e '' -o auto base_file file1) file2
```

Here, we first join `base_file` and `file1`, then join the result with `file2`.

**Explanation :**

- `join -a 1 -t, -e '' -o auto base_file file1` :

  - `-a 1` : displays the fields of `base_file` even if there is no match in the `file1`
  - `-t,` : we treat the character `,` as our field separator. This impacts both the input files and the output of the function.
  - `-e '' -o auto` : when a field is not present, output the string `''`. The `-e` option is dependant on the `-o` option. `-o auto` is the default output format.

**Output :**

```
aa,Apple,1
ab,Orange,2
ac,Mango,
ad,,
ae,,3
```

Answer (score 1):

awk way:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2}FILENAME==ARGV[2]{b[$1]=$2}
                   FILENAME==ARGV[3]{print $0,a[$0],b[$0]}' f1 f2 base
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work in any awk for any number of input files:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
!seen[$1]++ { keys[++numKeys] = $1 }
FNR==1 { ++numFiles }
{ a[$1,numFiles]=$2 }
END {
    for (keyNr=1; keyNr <= numKeys; keyNr++) {
        key = keys[keyNr]
        printf "%s%s", key, OFS
        for (fileNr=2;fileNr<=numFiles;fileNr++) {
            printf "%s%s", a[key,fileNr], (fileNr<numFiles ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk base file1 file2
aa,Apple,1
ab,Orange,2
ac,Mango,
ad,,
ae,,3
```

Comment: Thanks dude, its working fine,  I have one more doubt , if my file having more columns how can be capture , example aa,Apple,100 , i need all colums in output like $1 -- common column and required $2,$3 file1 and $2 of file2

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you're asking. You've got multiple answers here to the question you asked so accept an answer here then post a followup question with a new [mcve] that demonstrates your new requirements. btw the idiomatic English word is `question`, not `doubt` - its a common but quite important mistake by non-native English speakers, esp from Asian countries. `doubt` means you don't believe something so it has a negative connitation while `question` just means you simply want to know the answer to something.